# What am I doing wrong trying to associate these two models in Sequelize JS?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models with a hasMany/belongsTo relationship. My database columns are setup like so:

**documents**

id | user_id | path

**queryables**

id | user_id| queryable_type | document_id

With corresponding associations in the model files:

```
Document.associate = (models) => {
  Document.belongsTo(models.User, {
    name: 'user_id',
    allowNull: false,
  });
  Document.hasMany(models.Queryable, { foreignKey: 'document_id', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
};
};
```

```
Queryable.associate = (models) => {
  Queryable.belongsTo(models.Document, { name: 'document_id', allowNull: false });
};
```

I am able to insert and query these tables without issue, however when I try to query on the association:

```
  const document = await Document.findByPk(req.params.id, {
    include:
      {
        model: Queryable,
      },
  });
```

I get the following error

```
/Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:565
      throw new sequelizeErrors.EagerLoadingError(`${targetModel.name} is not associated to ${this.name}!`);
            ^

EagerLoadingError [SequelizeEagerLoadingError]: Queryable is not associated to Document!
    at Document._getIncludedAssociation (/Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:565:13)
    at Document._validateIncludedElement (/Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:502:53)
    at /Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:421:37
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Document._validateIncludedElements (/Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:417:39)
    at Document.findAll (/Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1124:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Document.findOne (/Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1240:12)
    at async Document.findByPk (/Users/jackcollins/inquirer/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1221:12)
    at async getDocument (file:///Users/jackcollins/inquirer/server/controllers/documentsController.js:162:20)

Node.js v19.8.1
```

I have tried `sequelize.sync()` to avail.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I shouldn't declare the association on both model files.

Commenting out the association method on Queryable.js resolved it

```
// Queryable.associate = (models) => {
//   Queryable.belongsTo(models.Document, { name: 'document_id', allowNull: false });
// };
```